# if i press a key initially it triggers the key press event but it doesn't give the value inside it .

Tags: jquery

if i pass a value "a" initially to input box it triggers the key press  event but it doesn't give the value inside it . but if i again pass 2nd a value "b"to the input box then it again triggers the key press event but it does not gives the current value (b in this case as current input) rather it gives the previous value a as output. 
    ===========================================================================

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>stop Propagation</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<button id="myBtn">click me </button>
<div class="test">
<h1>click this</h1>
</div>

<input type="text">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="stopPro.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Java script- (stopPro.js) --> here

```
$("input[type='text']").click(function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
}
);


$("input[type='text']").keypress(function()
    {   
        console.log("key pressed");
        console.log(this.value);

      }
    );
```

[image: here is the output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with the order of operations.

[`keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) is fired while the key is being pressed down (though as the jQuery API notes, this behavior can vary between browsers). As such, the input's value hasn't actually been updated yet when that `console.log` was being triggered. I've updated the `keypress` event in my example to show a useful way to use it by checking the `event` to see which key was pressed.

Instead, for checking the input's value, you can use [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/), which fires as the user releases the keyboard key, and after the key has been typed.

```js
$("input[type='text']").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
  .keypress(function(event) {
    console.log('keypress (key)', event.key);
  })
  .keyup(function() {
    console.log('keyup (value)', this.value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">

  <button id="myBtn">click me </button>
  <div class="test">
    <h1>click this</h1>
  </div>

  <input type="text">

</div>
```